# Does a brain age faster when depressed? And would that be a bad thing?

Tags: depression

Websites are reporting

> Research shows your brain physically ages faster when you're depressed

Sources  [1](https://qz.com/1551817/research-shows-your-brain-physically-ages-faster-when-youre-depressed/) [2](https://psychology-spot.com/depression-brain-aging/) [3](https://www.worldhealth.net/news/depression-increases-your-brain-age/)

I wonder how exact that research can be, when including such vague (as in: Surely not easily quantifiable?) ideas as *brain age* and *depression*.

It seems the source of this "news" is a [2004 study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC486942/) discussing depression and physical symptoms. Maybe there has been a follow up concentrating on the "aging faster" part of the claim?

Comment: By "aging faster" they might mean that the brains of people with depression show physical traits usually only present in older people, not necessarily "you're 30 but your brain is 47"

Comment: That would certainly be an interesting correlation

Comment: Your second link cites several papers: John, A. et. Al. (2018) Affective problems and decline in cognitive state in older adults: a systematic review and meta-analysis. Perry, V. H. (2018) Microglia and major depression: not yet a clear picture. Cepeda, M. S. et. Al. (2016) Depression Is Associated With High Levels of C-Reactive Protein and Low Levels of Fractional Exhaled Nitric Oxide: Results From the 2007-2012 National Health and Nutrition Examination Surveys. Magouirk, B. et. Al. (2012) C-Reactive Protein is Related to Memory and Medial Temporal Brain Volume in Older Adults.